# Initialize a vector directly in parameter list of function call

Tags: c++, vector

I would consider this an easy task, but I did not find a solution yet:

This works:

```
vector<A*> v = vector<A*>{a1, a2};
b->add(v);
```

This does not compile (method can not be resolved):

```
b->add(vector<A*>{a1, a2});
```

Signature of add:

```
void add(vector<A*>& v);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the signature of `add`? Does it take its argument by reference?

Comment: By non-const lvalue reference, specifically. If so, it makes no sense to pass a temporary because the whole point is to modify the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`add` takes a `vector<A*>&`. Temporaries cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference. If `add` does not modify its argument, you can change the signature to `void add(const vector<A*>&)`, allowing you to pass temporaries.